# Lie algebra of $G \times H$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

We have to prove that the Lie algebra of $G \times H$ is $\mathfrak{g}\oplus \mathfrak{h}$.

We know that $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$ and $\mathfrak{h}=T_eH$. But is it true that $T_e(G\times H)=T_eG\oplus T_eH$?

How to approach this question?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a general fact about manifolds: $T_{(p,q)}(M\times N) \cong T_pM\oplus T_qN$. So ${\rm Lie}(G\times H) = T_{(e,e)}(G\times H) \cong T_eG\oplus T_eH = \mathfrak{g}\oplus \mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks for the solution. I got it.